# Query columns with a particular data type from a table (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 100+ columns with char, int, and numeric datatypes 
but I don't know how they are placed within the table. Is it possible 
to query columns with only one of those datatypes?

I have tried for 'numeric' type where I find the column names from 
information_schema. I then used 'with' and tried to use that to 
extract the columns that matches with the query contained in 'with'. 
It didn't work because the 'column_name' in the last line is not 
valid. Any suggestion how to get it right?

```
WITH numeric_columns AS
    (SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema='table_admin' and 
    table_name='my_table' 
    AND data_type='numeric')
SELECT * from table_admin.my_table 
WHERE column_name (????) IN (SELECT * FROM numeric_columns);
```

Comment: Do *not* use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql to build a string using the column names you get from your CTE. I'm not well versed in postgresql, so instead of a real answer, I'll point you toward the postresql documentation on using dynamic sql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You are trying to query a table for a specific list of columns that is determined dynamically by their type? Why? At any rate the keyword here is "Dynamic". You'll have to dynamically generate a sql statement based on your results from the sql in your CTE and then execute that SQL... If I'm guessing correctly.

Comment: let's assume that don't know the column names of a table but I only know that the table has various data types. I just want to pull columns with only one datatypes. I can do it in two steps. 1. query the table to get the names of the columns with a particular datatype and then 2) query the table again but this time typing the names of those columns by hand. I just want to combine both steps in one query.

Comment: You do it in two steps.  It's possible to write dynamic SQL that can do both steps for you, but you're still technically doing it in two steps.  It's very odd to not be able to know what columns exist until execution time.  Database schemas should not change like that.  Your question is so odd that it almost sounds like you're confusing rows and columns.

Comment: Bacon: thanks for the comment but I totally disagree with the part of your comment that says "... is so odd that ...". To you it might be so but to me it is something I need to solve and hence I am seeking help without 
 warranting any unconstructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a plpgsql function. Because the number of columns is unknown you have to merge them in some way into a single column. One of suitable ways is to use [jsonb.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)

Example function:

```
create or replace function numeric_cols(sname text, tname text)
returns setof jsonb language plpgsql as $$
declare
    select_list text;
begin
    select string_agg(column_name, ',')
    into select_list
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_schema = sname 
    and table_name = tname
    and data_type = 'numeric';

    return query
    execute format($fmt$
        select to_jsonb(t)
        from (
            select %s
            from %I.%I
            ) t
        $fmt$, select_list, sname, tname);
end $$;
```

Example usage:

```
create schema if not exists table_admin;
create table table_admin.my_table(id serial primary key, n1 numeric, n2 numeric, t1 text);
insert into table_admin.my_table (n1, n2, t1) values
(100, 200, 'first'),
(200, 300, 'second');

select *
from numeric_cols('table_admin', 'my_table');

      numeric_cols      
------------------------
 {"n1": 100, "n2": 200}
 {"n1": 200, "n2": 300}
(2 rows)
```